# How to setup a slave replication of mysql database for development?

Tags: mysql, linux

I've set up a slave replication of MySQL database. And for development requirements, I want to write sth into the slave database, but it would cause the broken of replication.

Since the database is huge, I don't want to restore the slave database from MySQL dump file every time after I finished some development work.

My requirement:

- All the changes in the slave database can be reverted by a simple command.
- The replication keeps working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use LVM filesystem snapshots. Before you begin testing:

1. Stop replication.
2. Take an LVM snapshot.
3. Do your tests. Replication is still off, but data is up to date

After you finish testing:

1. Stop mysqld.
2. Restore the snapshot. This reverts all files to the state they were at the moment you created the LVM snapshot above.
3. Start mysqld and start replication. It will need to catch up and apply all changes since you stopped replication before your testing. This will take a little while, depending on how many changes happened on your master database.

See https://www.tecmint.com/take-snapshot-of-logical-volume-and-restore-in-lvm/ for a nice tutorial on using LVM snapshots.

This method only works if your development database instance is on Linux.

Comment: you remind me of using the snapshot of virtual machine software, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the new records using a primary key that is not expected to be used by the master database (e.g. add a sufficiently large offset like 2^10 or negative numbers if allowed...).

In this way, the insertions coming from the master won't clash.